# AS3 Getting the day offset compared to the current date

Tags: actionscript-3, date

I need a function which compares the incoming parameters (day, month, year) with the current date. This function should return 0 for yesterday, 1 for the current day, 2 for tomorrow, 3 for the day after tomorrow...

I already have this function:

```
private function getNumberOfDay(day:int, month:int, year:int):int
        {
            var date: Date = new Date();

            if(date.month+1 == month && date.fullYear == year)
            {
                if(date.date == day)
                    return 1;
                else if(date.date + 1 == day)
                    return 2;
                else if(date.date + 2 == day)
                    return 3;
                else if(date.date + 3 == day)
                    return 4;
                else if(date.date + 4 == day)
                    return 5;
                else if(date.date + 5 == day)
                    return 6;
                else if(date.date - 1 == day)
                    return 0;
            }
            return -1;
        }
```

It works so far very good, but now imagine that our current date ist the 31.12.2012 and I call this:

var numberOfDay:int = getNumberOfDay(1, 1, 2013);

it should return 2, but the month is not the same like our current month (same with the year). So the function returns -1. What can I do? Many thanks in advance!!

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0_de/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Date.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will never get what you want with the function you created.
You have to basically convert the dates you want to compare to a time stamp value.
Time stamps are the number of milliseconds from the epoch date. 1-1-1970.
If you take the difference of the time stamps then it just a simple process to calculate the amount of days difference.

```
function getNumberOfDay(day:int, month:int, year:int):int{
    // remember month is base 0 so january is 0 and dec is 11
    var millisecondsPerDay:int = 24*60*60*1000; //86400000
    var testDate:Date = new Date(year,month,day)
    var currentDate:Date = new Date()
    var days:int = Math.ceil((testDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime())/millisecondsPerDay);
    // return the value plus 1 since you are offseting the from yesterday and not today
    return ++days;
}

trace('tomorrow --------------- ' + getNumberOfDay( 4, 5, 2012 )) //2
trace('yesterday -------------- ' + getNumberOfDay( 2, 5, 2012 )) // 0
trace('sometime in the future - ' + getNumberOfDay( 1, 1, 2013 )) // 244
trace('sometime in the past --- ' + getNumberOfDay( 1, 1, 2012 )) // -122
trace('3 days from yesteday --- ' + getNumberOfDay( 5, 5, 2012 )) // 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a little bit of Google got me this code

```
public static function getDaysBetweenDates(date1:Date,date2:Date):int

{

       var one_day:Number = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
       var date1_ms:Number = date1.getTime();
       var date2_ms:Number = date2.getTime();
       var difference_ms:Number = Math.abs(date1_ms - date2_ms);
       return Math.round(difference_ms/one_day);
}
```

The above should work and my advice would be to use it. If you want to correct your algorithm instead, go ahead and add an `else` after `if (date.fullYear == year)`.

So if the `else` is executed it means the years did not match, then add the algorithm to find know how many days are between two dates in different years (This again might be long)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following code:

and we all know, the date after 2013-11-24 23:59 is 2013-11-25.

```
public static function getDateOffset2(year:int,month:int,date:int):int
{
    var oneDay:Number = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    var now:Date = new Date();
    var firstDate:Date = new Date(year,month-1,date);

    var secondDate:Date = new Date(now.fullYear,now.month,now.date);
    var offset:Number = Math.abs(firstDate.time - secondDate.time);
    return offset/oneDay;
}
```